# xUnit test project don't started (VS2022, NET Core 5)

Tags: .net-core, xunit, visual-studio-2022

I have my old workable xUnit test project. It was worked fine in another computer with VS2019. But in another computer with VS2022 project don't start. I have recreated project again, reinstall Net Core SDK, a couple of time restart my computer and Visual Studio. But any my attempt was filed.

This is my project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>BackendApiTest1</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="BackendAPI">
       <HintPath>..\..\..\BackendAPI\BackendAPI\bin\Debug\net5.0\BackendAPI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[Test project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhC07.png)

Project build without errors. Menu on test explorer opened once, I can click run or debug and after that never happens.

Comment: If your run the tests via the command line with “dotnet test” does it work?

Comment: thank you @scottdavidwalker. This is cool method. But finally I found a reason. Maybe new studio compilation don't allow some type of explicit conversion. I changes in test project this code JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response)("token") to code JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response)("token").ToString and test project running. However I don't see any error messages. I have not understand what happens when finally error message appears in test project. I simple delay this project to 2 days and after two days unexpectedly error message is appear. I change one code line and test project going.